# Publish visualizations / dashboard

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I am trying to work on a Pie Chart and want to display the count instead of percentage. Is there any option to do so or how can I do that?

Secondly, once its done, what is the process to publish the dashboard so that every one can access it?

As I am new to Foundry, any guidance or heads ups much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some additional details - where are you building this chart? Contour, Quiver, Workshop?

Comment: Hi @LoganRhyne its in Contour.

Comment: hey @Krish_D this question has multiple questions in one and may not be appropriate for stack overflow. Perhaps you can split them as well as including examples of code or configuration that you have already tried.